# Import YAML file into Mathematica

Tags: import, data-format

Has anyone implemented the import of [YAML data files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) into Mathematica?  I suppose some sort of transformation into a nested list of rules would be the way to do it.  Thanks

Comment: There are many YAML parsers for Java, and Mathematica has J/Link. It should be possible to use those two together.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote such a cross-platform tool to convert other formats to wolfram format: [WolframExchange](https://github.com/GalAster/wolfram-exchange-cli)

#### Usage

```sh
wex in.yml      # check file but no output
wex in.yml -t   # output only text
wex in.yml -c   # output only binary
wex in.yml -ct  # output both text and binary
```

#### Result

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is very cool!

Answer (score 5):

I just wrote an importer: https://github.com/zbjornson/MYaml. It's built on [SnakeYAML](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml) and supports all language-independent types.

Example 2.10 from the spec:

```
In[1]:= ImportString["---
 hr:
   - Mark McGwire
   # Following node labeled SS
   - &SS Sammy Sosa
 rbi:
   - *SS # Subsequent occurrence
   - Ken Griffey", "YAML"]
Out[1]= {
          "hr" -> {"Mark McGwire", "Sammy Sosa"}, 
          "rbi" -> {"Sammy Sosa", "Ken Griffey"}
        }
```

More examples in [the test suite](https://github.com/zbjornson/MYaml/blob/master/Test/Test.mt).

Comment: For demonstration purposes, can you show how your importer acts on a sample YAML file?

Comment: @J.M. good call, added an example.

Comment: Consider posting it on http://packagedata.net/ too

Comment: Another importer was written just a few days ago, see at the end of comment thread here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127300/12

Comment: Added to packagedata, thanks. :)

Comment: I got a successful "Installed YAML importer to..." and restarted the kernel, but if I try to use it with `Import` or `ImportString` I get the error "`The Import element "YAML" is not present when importing as Text`".  I believe this is because it's not recognizing the `"YAML"` as a data format and is falling back and assuming it's a specified element of the data.  Anyway to troubleshoot this?

Comment: @JessRiedel You're correct. I'm not on a computer with *M* right now but can double check in the morning that a fresh install works. What version of *M* are you using? You can try manually loading [this](https://github.com/zbjornson/MYaml/blob/master/YAML/Import.m) file to register the importer, something like `<< FileNameJoin[{$BaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Formats", "YAML", "Import.m"}]`.

Comment: Gah, it turns out I just needed to use `$UserBaseDirectory` instead of `$BaseDirectory`.  The folder at `$BaseDirectory` doesn't actually exist on my machine, and the installation code fails silently in this case (which is totally reasonable given the audience size; I should have just checked things more carefully).  Thanks much for your fast help.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. I'll try to make it print a helpful error in that situation.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot find a YAML importer, consider converting the YAML to [JSON](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/JSON.html) and importing that.  It'll give you the list of rules you'd expect.